# issues with 1D java array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm getting a null pointer exception in one of my java classes.
I have been looking at this thing for ever now and I could use another set of eyes.
I have 2 Class files:
FileParser:

```
    /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package photouploader;
import java.nio.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

/**
 *

 * @author 10339
 */
public class fileParser {
    /*var Decleration*/
    private File dir;
    private File [] Files;
    public String [] Filernames; 

    /*Accessor Methods*/
    public File getDir(){
        return dir;
    }
    public void SetDir(File directory){
        dir=directory;
    }
    public File[] getFiles(){
        return Files;
    }
    public void setFiles(File [] matches){

            Files=matches.clone();
        }
        public String [] getFilenames(){
            return Filernames;
        }
        public void setFilenames(){

        for(int i=0;i<Files.length;i++){
            System.out.println(Files[i].toString());
            System.out.println(Files[i].toString().substring(Files[i].toString().lastIndexOf("\\")+1));
            Filernames[i]=Files[i].toString().substring(Files[i].toString().lastIndexOf("\\")+1);
        }
    }
}
```

Photo Uploader Class file/Main:

```
package photouploader;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;

/**
 *
 * @author 10339
 */
public class PhotoUploader {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
    JFileChooser j = new JFileChooser();
    j.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    int returnVal = j.showOpenDialog(null);


    if(returnVal == javax.swing.JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        File dir = j.getSelectedFile();
        File[] matches = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter()
        {
            public boolean accept(File dir,String name)
            {

               return name.endsWith(".png")||name.endsWith(".jpg");
            }

        });

        if(matches.length==0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"you have not chosen "
                + "a valid directory");
        }
        else{
            fileParser FP = new fileParser();
            FP.setFiles(matches);
            FP.setFilenames();
          /*  Form FJP = new Form();
            FJP.setVisible(true);*/

            NewJFrame JP = new NewJFrame();
            JP.setVisible(true);
            JP.update_Upload_list(FP.getFilenames());
        }


    }
    else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"you have not chosen "
                + "a valid directory");
    }
    }
    }
```

I have attempted to just place data @ position 0 of Filternames and it is still freaking out.
Have I missed something?
do I need to Declare the size of the Array before use?
Thanks,
Scorliss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to allocate memory for the array elements:

```
Filernames = new String[Files.length];
```

EDIT:

> So declaration is not enough?

No. In a nutshell, when you declare the variable, you are just saying that "this variable will point to an array". In that moment, it doesn't hold any array at all. You have to asign an array to the variable in order to use it. You can read a bit more about array basics [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Comment: THX that was it. So declaration is not enough?

Comment: Thanks for that Racso. I'll dive a bit deeper.

Answer (score 0):

The String[] Filernames, has not been declared like: String[] Filernames = new String[5]; 
(or = new String[some length];) Also you should follow Java code conventions such as only class names begin with a capital letter, and variable names start with lower case letters.